# Why is indexing via sub2ind not the same as indexing via A(i, j) in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Assume that you have this matrix

```
>> P = zeros(8, 12)
P =

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

And you want to add `1` on each coordinate. If it's the same coordinate, it will be `+1`.

```
>> angles = [1 2 1 3 3 2 5 6 2 1 3 8]
angles =

   1   2   1   3   3   2   5   6   2   1   3   8

>> r = [1 2 4 2 5 6 1 4 6 6 3 6]
r =

   1   2   4   2   5   6   1   4   6   6   3   6
```

If I use `sub2ind`

```
>> indices = sub2ind(size(P), angles, r);
>> P(indices) = P(indices) + 1;
>> P
P =

   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

But if I using normal indexing

```
>> for k = 1:length(r)
      P(angles(k), r(k)) = P(angles(k), r(k)) + 1;
   end
>> P
P =

   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

If you look closely, there is a `2` inside the matrix `P`, but not inside the matrix `P` above.

**Question:**

Why does `sub2ind` indexing differ from regular `P(i, j)` indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference arises because there is a pair of coordinates repeated (marked in boldface here):

```
angles = [1 2 1 3 3  5 6  1 3 8]
r =      [1 2 4 2 5  1 4  6 3 6]
```

---

In the `sub2ind` version, the repeated pair of coordinates causes `indices` to have a repeated value. The line `P(indices) = P(indices)+1;` only adds `1` **once** to that entry of `P`. This is not related to `ind2sub`, it's just the way indexed assignment works: the changes are **not "accumulated"**, so a repeated entry acts **on the original value**, without regard of previous occurrences of the same entry. For example:

```
>> x = [10 20 30];
ind = [2 3 3];
x(ind) = x(ind)+1
x =
    10    21    31
```

Or, perhaps more clearly, note how the value `50` is useless here:

```
>> x = [10 20 30];
>> x([2 3 3]) = [40 50 60]
x =
    10    40    60
```

---

On the other hand, in the `for` version you **explicitly accumulate** the changes, so if an entry appears twice you add `1` **twice** to that entry.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a simpler implementation, this is the sort of thing [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) is designed for.

```matlab
>> accumarray([angles', r'], 1, size(P))

ans =

     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: "Simpler"... once you've understood how the admittedly somewhat difficult to master `accumarray` function works. But once you've mastered that function, you can do lots of things with it...